# Qt, событие на пункте QMenuBar

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется верхнее меню, в виде нескольких пунктов, где несколько пунктов меню представляют из себя кнопки, без вложенных пунктов. Полный код меню(имеется класс - окно, и у него в конструкторе все создается):

```
   MainWindow::MainWindow(const QString name): ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
   {
      ui->setupUi(this);
      this->setWindowTitle(name);

      menuBar()->addMenu(scan = new QMenu(tr("Сканировать")));
      menuBar()->addMenu(options = new QMenu(tr("Настройки")));
      menuBar()->addMenu(about = new QMenu(tr("О программе")));
      menuBar()->addMenu(info = new QMenu(tr("Использование")));

      QAction* action = menuBar()->addAction(tr("Выход"));
      connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(close()));
   }
```

Однако, это событие не срабатывает так, как нужно. При запуске,у приложения имеется кнопка выход, но при нажатии на ней открывается список подменю-элементов, где есть элемент "активировать", который не действителен. Как надо правильно сделать единичный пункт меню?

Comment: Добавьте весь код формирования меню

Comment: @tequillaz добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [метод quit()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#quit). Метод `close` закроет текущий виджет и само приложение, если это был последний видимый виджет.

Пример использования:

```
QPushButton *quitButton = new QPushButton("Quit");
connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
```

Если `&app` недоступен вам в текущем контексте можно заменить его на макрос [qApp](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qapplication.html#qApp):

```
...
connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79770/discussion-on-answer-by-gil9red-qt----qmenubar).